# how to add rel to link in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

to show light-box

```
<a href="images/image-1.jpg" rel="lightbox">
<img src="images/thumb-1.jpg" width="100" height="40" alt="" />
</a>
```

i use this code to show images in lightbox instead the above code ..

```
$full = '/img/images/image-1.jpg';
  $thumb = $this->Html->image('images/thumb-1.jpg');
echo $this->Html->link($thumb,$full,array('escape' => false));
```

already i show images (thumb and full screen) but i didn't show the
popup effect when clicked on the first image because i don't know how to add **rel="light-box"** to the
link

Comment: triple-posting it doesnt really help anybody

Comment: @mark: Mind linking to his earlier posts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're pretty close. The third param in the link function is an array of HTML attributes, so this should do it:

```
echo $this->Html->link($thumb,$full,array('escape' => false, 'rel' => 'light-box'));
```

Source: http://api.cakephp.org/class/html-helper#method-HtmlHelperlink

UPDATE: This link is even more helpful http://book.cakephp.org/view/1442/link

Comment: something wrong..the popup lighttbox still not work..i see images but wihout jquery effects

Comment: Does the rel="light-box" appear in the source? If it does, your question has been answered and it would be nice if you could accept/upvote my answer. You can then post the new problem in a new question.

Comment: this is the generated html code <a href="http://localhost/tet/img/images/image-1.jpg" rel="lightbox">
              <img src="17_files/thumb-1.jpg" alt="" height="40" width="200"></a>

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. I do have some ideas about your lightbox problem, but that should probably get its own question to avoid confusion. If you've opened one, can you link from here?